What is name of this component?
I have  several obsolete IDE SV1021h harddrive but one of them is not able to power on with molex cable.
I compared PCB of this broken SV1021h harddrive with working PCB by checking ohm value of most of IC components.
And I finally found that ohm value of unknown component(which is written "0G 22 25V - +" on its surface),which is shown in the below picture and very close to molex male connector, is very different(550 ohm) to that of same component in the working PCB(29k ohm)
So I think that If I find out name of this unknown IC component,It would be possible to revive broken IDE SV1021h harddrive.
Is there anyone who knows the name of this IC component?


Do you have pictures from other angles and showing the surrounding circuitry? Could be a tantalum capacitor.

https://i.ibb.co/fFHKjSd/IMG-20241018-110715.jpg https://i.ibb.co/m4cKQqj/IMG-20241018-110729.jpg https://i.ibb.co/vkftbQ7/IMG-20241018-110749.jpg https://i.ibb.co/020HCfk/IMG-20241018-110816.jpg https://i.ibb.co/RDP7xTK/IMG-20241018-110831.jpg https://i.ibb.co/C7Qr60M/IMG-20241018-110833.jpg https://i.ibb.co/JyDx1Zy/IMG-20241018-110849.jpg https://i.ibb.co/wh9hz2q/IMG-20241018-110903.jpg https://i.ibb.co/s38XSLY/IMG-20241018-112151.jpg https://i.ibb.co/ThhSmqd/IMG-20241018-112156.jpg https://i.ibb.co/QjxcYL6/IMG-20241018-112204.jpg https://i.ibb.co/c1syRtX/IMG-20241018-112209.jpg

https://i.ibb.co/zVf6qhh/IMG-20241018-112211.jpg All of them is pictures which was taken from most of angle and surrounding components.

please do not comment on your own question ... if you have anything to add then edit the question

It appears to be a tantalum electrolytic capacitor. 22uF/25V
However such parts are typically connected across supply rails and a low in-circuit resistance does not really help much other than to indicate that something on that rail is shorted.
Tantalum caps tend to fail in rather more dramatic fashion with charring and maybe flames, so my best guess is that there is a shorted semiconductor somewhere.

Thank you very much for reply! I compared with more components of working PCB and As you pointed out,It seems that a component,which is written 8G0S(QFT1) on its surface, has different resistance to working one(Resistance between the largest pin and downmost pin was 500 ohm but when I measured same component in the working PCB it was 2k ohm)  i.ibb.co/s38XSLY/IMG-20241018-112151.jpg

By the way, Is it Okay to purchase any  tantalum electrolytic capacitor which has 25v 22uf specification in order to replace this suspicious component?

I just have desoldered this suspicious components and it is measured 18.5uf capacitance,I think its capacitance have been decrepit more than 10% tolerance So It need to be replaced..

I would call that close enough not to affect functionality.

@bshi02  Most capacitors come with a 20% tolerance.
